# How to move the items that are out of the screen into the content area during AnimatedVisibility animation in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In this video, for the items that are at the top, `AnimatedVisibility` works perfectly, but for the items that last, it doesn't bring them up in the visible content area after the card is expanded.

https://youtu.be/L0jMZQR_Omo

Is there a way, by using which I can instruct to bring the composable to the visible content area?

You can find the code here:
https://gist.github.com/chinmaydash007/1495bf91d34f4b79212c36a08e243fe6

Comment: Please share your code not videos

Answer (score 0):

The bringIntoViewRequester might be what you are searching for.
I'm not going to post a code snippet as the example on the documentation page is very good. Check out the second code snippet there:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/relocation/BringIntoViewResponder

I would say instead of putting the code
bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
To InFocusChanged(), put it in the onClick function of your button and the

Modifier.bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester)

In the lowest element that should be visible when you click on the button.